# Dynamic Linq Sort not working for ArrayList

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dynamic, arraylist

I am trying to do something like the following

```
string orderedBy = "item.length";

    var sorted = from PPart item in partList
                 orderby orderedBy
                 select item;
```

where partList is an array list containing PPart type objects. The above statement is not sorting the arrayList.

If i write the item.length directly in the linq query, something like below, then the list is sorting

```
 var sorted = from PPart item in partList
                             orderby item.length
                             select item;
```

How can i make dynamic linq to work with late binding

Comment: Standard LINQ does not support that.

Comment: SLaks i am using library "Dynamic Linq"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using Expression Trees, for example:

```
    public static Func<PPart, IComparable> GetOrderByPropertyExpression(string propertyName)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (PPart));
        PropertyInfo baseProperty = typeof (PPart).GetProperty(propertyName);
        Expression memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, baseProperty);

        return
            Expression.Lambda<Func<PPart, IComparable>>(Expression.TypeAs(memberExpression, typeof (IComparable)),
                                                        parameter).Compile();
    }
```

And use it as following:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<PPart> ordered = partList.OrderBy(PPart.GetOrderByPropertyExpression("length"));
```

No error-checking provided, just a concept.